# Atualizar tela de aviso

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2015

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de controle de estoque e frente de caixa e pretendo criar uma tela de aviso no form principal (pode ser com datagridview), onde, se ao vender determinado produto e o mesmo atingir o limite mínimo de estoque, então a tela de aviso deve exibir esse aviso automaticamente.
Até o momento, a única alternativa em que consegui pensar, é colocar essa tela de aviso para atualizar automaticamente a cada 1 minuto, mas ainda sim não seria algo on-line.

Qual a melhor alternativa possível para esse desenvolvimento? Por favor não quero deixar o sistema pesado, quero algo LEVE!

Obrigado!
Abs!

Comment: Sua pergunta envolve muitas variáveis, você deve estudar seu cenário, desenvolver  e depois tentar ajuda com algo mais específico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras de resolver isso. Mas como vc explicitou que não quer dicionar nada no sistema atual, para o manter "level", o melhor que eu vejo é [criar um serviço windows](http://blog.albertomonteiro.net.br/2016/04/12/criando-windows-service-com-c-de-forma-facil/) para, periodicamente, chegar o nivel do estoque, e [enviar uma notificação](https://github.com/thiagolunardi/AzureNotificationHub).

Assim você não adiciona novo códigos ao projeto atual, libera seu *client* de ter mais uma responsabilidade, e usa um recurso nativo do Windows 10.